# Javascript cannot encode the £ sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8

I have `<meta charset="utf-8" />` on my website, my files are in UTF-8 encoding and I have put `charset="utf-8"` on the script tag - and it still doesn't work.

Below is my code

```
<input type="text" id="danewcontent1" name="danewcontent1" 
value="£890">

<script charset="utf-8">
function escapePercent(str) {
  return str.replace(/%/g, '%25');
}

$(function() {
    var post_id = 1;
    var daplaincontent = $("#danewcontent1").val();
    alert(daplaincontent);
    var danewcontent = escapePercent(escape(daplaincontent));
    prompt("Copy the value below into http://urldecode.org and keep clicking decrypt", danewcontent);

    // decode the URLEncode here, and keep clicking "decode"
    // https://urldecode.org
});
</script>
```

It encodes `£` as `%25A3890` which is `%A3890` decoded which is `�890` decoded.

I have a JS Fiddle illustrating this problem here.
https://jsfiddle.net/desbest/dyz9zta6/

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: I assume you need to encode the pound-sign (currency sign) in order to pass it via a URL? Why is this a requirement? Or is there something I'm missing? Please provide context for what you're trying to do overall. You might be trying to solve the problem in a different way than you need to.

Comment: @guest271314 The expected result is that javascript successfully encodes the `£` sign which I can test by going to http://urldecode.org

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy I'm using ajax POST so I can update my database. I don't need to encode what is being sent through POST as I'm not using GET, but I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to stop trying to re-invent the wheel and use built-in browser encoding and decoding. Your simply handling the escape the way you do is not working for you.

```js
$(function() {
    var post_id = 1;
    var daplaincontent = $("#danewcontent1").val();
    alert(daplaincontent);
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(daplaincontent);
    alert(encoded);
    var decoded = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
    alert(decoded); // this gives back the £890
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="danewcontent1" name="danewcontent1" 
value="£890">
```